# Does a hosting support MVC5 as long as it supports .NET4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, hosting

How can I know if a shared hosting supports MVC5? Many hosting companies only state that they support .Net 4.5, 4.0, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0 Framework and ASP.NET. They don't state specifically if they support MVC5.

Coming from the PHP world, I'm still very new to ASP.net and its MVC framework. Is it right to say that as long as the server supports ASP.net and .NET 4.0 and above, all I have to do is just upload my web application (the asp files) together with MVC5 framework binaries to my account and it will work?

In other words, the server doesn't really need to "support" MVC5, but just need the .NET 4 runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 5 requires .NET 4.5 at least.

You need to find out with the hosting company if they support .Net 4.5.

If they do then you can use MVC 5.

You can also try by uploading a .net 4.5 compiled version "Hello World" program and see if you can host the same.

Sometime shared hosting don't update what they are supporting. However, they have already installed latest .Net Framework on their windows machine; thanks to auto windows update :)

Good luck

Comment: I see. So I can safely say that as long as the hosting company supports .NET 4.5, it supports MVC5, right? And it's just a matter of uploading the MVC framework onto the server.

Comment: You don't install MVC framework. You install .Net 4.5. When you will deploy the .net application, it will have MvC dll dependencies. Thus, as long as your website is hosted on .Net 4.5 framework it will work.

Comment: Don't forget IIS. The other requirement is that they need to have the IIS extensionless module installed for MVC to properly route.

Comment: he has mentioned about they are supporting other mvc version.